# Unable to send key combination `SHFT+F3` via SendMessage/PostMessage : vc++

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to send key press event to another application via `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` in Visual C++.

I know I can simulate single key like <kbd>F3</kbd> using `SendMessage/PostMessage`.
but, I don't know how to send key combination like <kbd>SHIFT+F3</kbd> using `SendMessage/PostMessage`.

I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendMessage/PostMessage are not appropriate for sending key press. See [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx):

> .. even if you manage to post the input messages into the target window's queue, that doesn't update the keyboard shift states. When the code behind the window calls the `GetKeyState` function or the `GetAsyncKeyState` function, it's going to see the "real" shift state and not the fake state that your posted messages have generated.
>
> The [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function was designed for injecting input into Windows. If you use that function, then at least the shift states will be reported correctly.

As you see Raymond already give you the solution too: use `SendInput` instead.